# Stack on a multi user Linux/Unix system

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How does stack function when installed on a multi user Linux/Unix system? Will stack share snapshot packages among the users? Any other issues of concerns?

I also found this related question interesting: [How do I install Haskell Stack locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206135/how-do-i-install-haskell-stack-locally) Is it not possible to install and use stack as a non-root user?

**Edit** (2017-11-06): My system admin don't want to install Haskell stack since this will save a lot of data in `~/.stack` for each user running Haskell stack. This is a real concern since each year we teach Haskell on a course with 130-150 students. To clarify (as in the comments of this question):

- Can Haskell stack be installed/used in such a way that snapshots are shared among users?

Comment: You _can_ install stack in the user home directory, without super user privileges. I just added [an according answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40721992/745903).

Comment: The question was closed as a duplicate, but I think it's not. It asks not “how to install stack in `/home/username`”, but how to install stack on a multi-user system in general.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2205

Comment: Exactly @leftaroundabout, my question is: 1) How to install stack on a multi-user system in general and 2) on a multi-user system, are snapshots shared among users?